# Subsequent line with 2 Typography on the same line using material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, typography

i'm haveing a little trouble to let a typography enter the second line without lefting the first, example:

[image]

I tried to cut unnecessary code here:

```
<Grid item container direction="column" >
{Array.isArray(x.sense) && x.sense && x.sense.map((x, index) => (
    <>
        {Array.isArray(x.gloss) ?
            <Grid item container direction="row">
                <Typography key={index} style={{ color: "#90a4ae", fontSize: "25px", }}>
                    {index + 1 + '. '}

                </Typography>
                <Typography key={index + 1} style={{ color: "#000000", fontSize: "25px", marginLeft: "5px" }}>
                    {x.gloss.toString().replace(/,/g, ', ')}

                </Typography>
            </Grid> : null
        }
    </>
))}
```

here like they stay on 'inspect element':

[image]

i already tried modifying rows, columns, nowarps, breakwords..but with short texts they stay on the same line, any clues?

**UPDATE** - just inserted a 'span' and works fine for me

```
<Typography key={index + 1} style={{ color: "#000000", fontSize: "25px", marginLeft: "5px" }}>
         <span style={{ color: "#90a4ae", fontSize: "25px", }}>{index + 1 + '. '}</span>
         {x.gloss.toString().replace(/,/g, ', ')} </Typography>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap `Typography` inside the `<Grid item />`

```
{
  Array.isArray(x.gloss) ? (
    <Grid container direction="row">
      <Grid item>
        <Typography key={index} style={{ color: "#90a4ae", fontSize: "25px" }}>
          {index + 1 + ". "}
        </Typography>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item>
        <Typography
          key={index + 1}
          style={{ color: "#000000", fontSize: "25px", marginLeft: "5px" }}
        >
          {x.gloss.toString().replace(/,/g, ", ")}
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  ) : null;
}
```

Comment: just did as you told, i removed the additional 'item' as well, but still the same, other than that i just have one main container but i dont think he affects it

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/thirsty-jackson-5n7ig?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark i commented with "problem here"